# on $(document).foundation(); Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using several foundation plugins on this page. Equalizer, and Reveal. When the foundation initializer is being called it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` on the `<script>$(document).foundation();</script>` call.

I assume it's related to the markup being parsed associated to one of the plugins. Here's the markup...

Equalizer...

```
   <div class="row" data-equalizer>
                <div class="overlay large-4 large-offset-4 columns clearfix">
                   ... text
                </div>
                <div class="large-4 columns clearfix">
                ... text
                </div>
   </div>
```

Reveal...

```
<a id="terms" href="terms.php" data-reveal-id="termsModal" target="_blank" data-reveal-ajax="terms.php">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></label>
```

Comment: Just a comment not directly related to your question: you don't need to use 'clearfix' class in your DIVs in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

After troubleshooting a bit more, I realized the [equalizer plugin](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html) was missing some markup.

I needed to add the `data-equalizer-watch` attribute on the child nodes.

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
   <div class="large-6 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
    ....
```